# Crash when open activity contain fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

• So i'm creating 2 fragments, testing "Inter-fragment communication" pattern:

• FragmentA contains a ListView, FragmentB contains a TextView.

In portrait mode: MainActivity contains FragmentA(listview), if user click on an item then move to AnotherActivity which contains FragmentB(textview) with some text..

• In lanescape mode: **MainActivity** contains both **FragmentA** and **B**..

• My lanescape mode worked fine, by in portrait mode if i click on an item, its crashed.

**FragmentA.java:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;
    Communicator comm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Log.d("this", "Done setting listview");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        comm.respone(arg2);
    }

    void setCommunicator(Communicator c) {
        comm = c;
    }

    public interface Communicator {
        public void respone(int index);
    }
}
```

**FragmentB.java:**

```
    public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView display;
    String[] data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_b, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        display = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Resources res = getResources();
        data = res.getStringArray(R.array.detail);
        Log.d("this", "Fragment B created ");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    void changeText(int index) {

        display.setText(data[index]);
        Log.d("this", "changing text");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentA.Communicator {

    FragmentA f1;
    FragmentB f2;
    FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        manager = getFragmentManager();
        f1 = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        f1.setCommunicator(this);

        Log.d("this", "setCommunicator");

    }

    @Override
    public void respone(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        Log.d("this", "f2 referenced from Main");
        if (f2 != null && f2.isVisible())// landscape
        {
            f2.changeText(index);
        } else // portrait
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

**AnotherActivity.java:**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {
    FragmentB f2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

        Log.d("this", "Another Activity");
        f2 = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        Log.d("this","fragment2 in Another Activity");
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int index = i.getIntExtra("index", 0);
        Log.d("this", "Get intent extras");
        if (f2 != null)
        {
            f2.changeText(index);
            Log.d("this", "changing text in Another Activity");
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmentdemo_2.MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo_2.FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_another.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmentdemo_2.AnotherActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo_2.FragmentB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_layout_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#addbb3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_layout_b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="..."
        android:background="#22c936"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fragmentdemo_2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AnotherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_another" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANOTHERACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

• Logcat:

```
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentdemo_2/com.example.fragmentdemo_2.AnotherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at com.example.fragmentdemo_2.FragmentB.changeText(FragmentB.java:38)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at com.example.fragmentdemo_2.AnotherActivity.onCreate(AnotherActivity.java:27)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
09-30 11:38:40.406: E/AndroidRuntime(14991):    ... 11 more
```

• Logcat with filter "this" :

```
09-29 22:02:16.098: D/this(7795): setCommunicator
09-29 22:02:16.098: D/this(7795): Done setting listview
09-29 22:02:36.848: D/this(7795): f2 referenced from Main
09-29 22:02:36.948: D/this(7795): Another Activity
09-29 22:02:36.948: D/this(7795): fragment2 in Another Activity
09-29 22:02:36.948: D/this(7795): Get intent extras
```

Please help, thanks in advance! (I'm a newbie in Java-Android)

Comment: Please post the exception message and stacktrace from your logcat. (Don't filter with "this".) It will show exactly what line in your code causes the NullPointerException.

Comment: Properly formatted and indented code will be easy to understand and you will get response faster. Please format your code.

Comment: Error says null pointer exception, check the line number and do debugging. Probably some object is not initialized before used

Comment: This is not proper way of doing multipane layout. Go through http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html. read before starting...

Comment: Problem is here `FragmentB.java:38` look at the code...or post here that line

Comment: I've learn these pattern from some tutorial on the internet, i'll read the Google's doc later, the app keeps crashing and i need to know to reason!

Comment: In your AnotherActivity you are calling method `changeText` using instance of your fragmentB where your FragmentB is actually not initialized and without initializing it you are trying access its views thats why its throwing nullpointer error to you.

Comment: RajaReddy PolamReddy: it's display.setText(data[index]);

Comment: GrIsHu: i initialize the TextView in onActivityCreated method, but when put the initialization in onCreateView, the results are the same

Comment: so you have to initialize that textview before showing text in that view

Comment: You are loading fragment wrongly.

Comment: What is line 38 of `FragmentB.java`?

Comment: Code-Apprentice: it's f2.changeText(index);

Comment: RajaReddy PolamReddy: i don't know what you mean? But i've tried initialize TextView in onCreateView and onActivityCreated, both didn't work

Comment: @DatHaVinh There is no line with `f2.changeText(index);` in the `FragmentB.java` code that you posted here...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry, it's display.setText(data[index]);

Comment: @DatHaVinh It looks like you have solved this problem. I just want to point out that the error message is telling you that either `display` or `data` is `null`. Hopefully you will be able to start solving errors like this on your own in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were not following the proper hierarchy of the fragment and activity. You can always access the views and methods of fragments after you load the fragment.

In your case you were indirectly passing the value from `MainActivity` to `FragmentA` and from `FragmentA` you were opening `AnotherActivity` which contains your `FragmentB`. In your case your were trying to pass value through intent from one fragment to another using an `Intent`, which not a valid way. You can always pass values between fragments through `Bundle` and get it from `Bundle`. 
Check out my changes below ,its working now. and do relevant changes according to your need.

Just do the following changes in your all the classes.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FragmentA f1;
    FragmentB f2;
    FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        manager = getFragmentManager();
        f1 = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        Log.d("this", "setCommunicator");

    }

   /* @Override
    public void respone(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        Log.d("this", "f2 referenced from Main");
        if (f2 != null && f2.isVisible())// landscape
        {
            f2.changeText(index);
        } else // portrait
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }*/

}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;
    Communicator comm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Log.d("this", "Done setting listview");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent i = new Intent(FragmentA.this.getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("index", arg2);
         startActivity(i);
    }

    void setCommunicator(Communicator c) {
        comm = c;
    }

    public interface Communicator {
        public void respone(int index);
    }
}
```

**AnotherActivity.java**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {
    FragmentB f2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

        FragmentManager mang = getFragmentManager();
        Log.d("this", "Another Activity");

        Log.d("this", "fragment2 in Another Activity");
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int index = i.getIntExtra("index", 0);
        Bundle bund = new Bundle();
        bund.putInt("val", index);
        f2 = (FragmentB) mang.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changeText(index);
        Log.d("this", "Get intent extras");

    }

}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView display;
    String[] data;
    int val;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View m_view;
        m_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_b, container, false);

        display = (TextView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
        data = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        Log.d("this", "Fragment B created ");
        return m_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void changeText(int index) {
        val=getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("index",0);
        display.setText(data[val]);
        Log.d("this", "changing text");
    }

}
```

Comment: It's still crash
Here some of the log:
09-30 12:17:33.812: E/AndroidRuntime(23532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 12:17:33.812: E/AndroidRuntime(23532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentdemo_2/com.example.fragmentdemo_2.AnotherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 12:17:33.812: E/AndroidRuntime(23532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

Comment: Yes, i did!

Here, in case i'm doing wrong:

<activity
            android:name=".AnotherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_another" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANOTHERACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Make your `changeText` method `public void`

Comment: Do post your layout file of `activity_another` and your fragment A & B classes layout file.

Comment: Please try to debug your code and let me know from where exactly its getting crashed? Tell me the line No: `fragmentdemo_2.FragmentB.changeText(FragmentB.java:38)` and `fragmentdemo_2.AnotherActivity.onCreate(AnotherActivity.java:27)` of your `FragmentB` and `AnotherActivity` files.

Comment: 38: f2.changeText(index);
27: if (f2 != null) {

Comment: line 38 in fragmentB is display.setText(data[index]); --- i think the problem maybe with the initialization of TextView by using getActivity() in onCreate() method, but i don't know how to deal with it...Debugging found Nullpointerexception in line 38 - fragmentB

Comment: I think there is no need of your `changeText` method as it contains only single line of code. You can initialize your `TextView` in your FragmentB inside `onCreateView` method and set the value there only.

Comment: What does your array `details` contains? @DatHaVinh

Comment: Your issue is resolved. I am updating my answer do check out. @DatHaVinh

Comment: still not working, you can download my project to check it out: http://www.mediafire.com/download/g0x0qo5hdy759tb/FragmentDemo_2.rar

Comment: You can just copy my code and check out its working on my side.